# Converting Adobe AIR to Flex 4.6 - mx.core.Window replacement

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm converting an AIR application to Flex 4.6.  Many of the AIR components use mx.core.Window.  Is there a replacement for that in Flex?

Thanks.

Comment: [spark.components.Window](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/Window.html) perhaps?

Comment: For the record, you're upgrading from Flex 3.x to Flex 4.6 (which is old. We are now on 4.11). AIR is just the runtime that allows AS3-based applications to run as desktop/mobile apps. The upgrade you are looking at is the MX->Spark framework (Spark was introduced as a replacement for MX in 4.0).You might want to Google for that since it is likely this own't be your only issue

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I have not been keeping up with the versions.I'm trying to keep the changes to a minimum, so I would prefer not to change versions, but I will look into 4.11.

Comment: RIAStar, Thank you for the suggestion.

I don't seem to have spark.components.Window in Flex.  There is a sparks.component package, with quite a few classes (I've used them in AIR), but Window is not there.  

Does that indicate some kind of set up problem?

Comment: I have issue like this with spark ViewNavigator, the problem was that i downloaded the AirSDK and compiler while i should use AirSDK, i deleted the Air SDK and downlad it again (but without compiler) and it worrked, not sure if this is your case.